# Adding image reference in markdown creates excessive text

Tags: bug, markdown

Some new behavior I've noticed in the past couple weeks is that whenever I click on the "add image" tool in the toolbar at the top of the standard editing view, a few extra (and unnecessary?) characters get added along with the reference to the image.

To be specific, here is what is automagically inserted into my answer when I drop an image in using the Stack Overflow image uploaded tool:

```
[![Some Text Goes Here][1]][1]
```

[image: Some Text Goes Here]

Whereas what it used to be, and what still works is:

```
![More Text Goes Here][2]
```

[image: More Text Goes Here]

Are the extra characters there for a reason or is this a bug in some template or?

Comment: It turns the inline image into a link, so that you can click on it and see it full-screen. I'm not sure why this change was made, it is really only good for people who post massive screenshots as images.

Comment: Meta dupe: [Extra square brackets and numbers when using automated link or add picture feature in questions and answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261863)

Comment: And [Support showing image in original size in overlay](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261182)

Comment: gah... I was looking for the dupe and didn't find it.  Attempting to close but I can't mark a duplicate answer on meta.stackexchange.com as a dupe (dupes need to exist on meta.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: What I don't like about the current solution is that the dotted line below an image looks more like a superfluous separator line than an indication for a link...

Answer (score 1):

This can actually be a great feature, if used correctly!

```
[![image][1]][1]
[--ref-text-][1]
```

What you have is an image that is also a link. By default now, if you just click on the image it is handled as a hyperlink, and takes you to the imgur-hosted image. That's a step up from the old behaviour.

***But wait, that's not all!***

By changing the second link reference to a different link, you can display one form of the image, but link it to another. It's a handy way to save space in the post while preserving a full-size & higher resolution image for clarity.

- Duplicate the link for `[1]` to `[2]`, and replace the outer reference with `[2]` as well.
- Shrink the displayed image by adding 's' or 'm' to the name for `[1]` (small or large, respectively)
- Optionally, add a tooltip by appending `(click to enlarge)` after the link for `[1]`.

Like this:

```
[![image][1]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXLhym.jpg (click to enlarge)
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXLhy.jpg
```

[image]